# C++/CLI and Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, c++-cli, entity-framework-5

I thought I'd try using EF 5 with C++/CLI in VS2012, so that I could try Code First. The package downloads via NuGet fine, but isn't visible to the solution.

On investigating, the Package Manager says that the package is not compatible with the version of the Framework being used by the solution, and requires 4.0 or 4.5... but the config for the project (a plain Win32 console app) says it is using v4.5.

Has anyone come across this and found a way to fix it?

Comment: This is an open work item for Nuget, mostly neglected.  The workaround is to retrieve it in a C# project and move the assemblies to your C++/CLI project directory, then add a reference.  http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/868

Comment: @HansPassant Could you expand on that a bit more?  Would do you mean by assemblies?  Are you referring to object code?

Comment: @HansPassant  Also, is there any update on this situation?

Comment: OK, I think you mean a .DLL in this case.  So build the EF link into a C# .DLL and move it to a C++ project?

Comment: In VS2013, EF 6.1 says it will download into a C++/CLI project (or even a C++ project) but then fails to do so, giving an error that an assembly (?) is not serializable.  It seems to be some kind of bug, as it should either work or refuse to download.  I don't think this is the nuget issue that Hans cited above; I think that got fixed and this is something else.